# Pending Developer Release update

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have my first app in Pending Developer Release. So, how I can update the app without releasing it? And  they have a shortly time review because it's an upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app has already been approved by Apple, you can no longer make updates without going through their approval process again.

Comment: Ok but. If I remove this build they see the new build like a update or a new app? (I need this info because the upgrade review is more faster than first app build review) @Oren

Comment: From my experience an update to an app isn't any faster to approve than a new app.

Comment: Are you sure of this?! watching http://appreviewtimes.com/ I've see some upgrate take like 1-4 days @Oren

Comment: My last app update took almost 30 days to get approved. On average my updates are taking about 11 days, which is consistent with the site and the same when I first submitted the app.

Comment: Hi @Mala Where did you see at the appreviewtimes.com that the review for an update is faster than the first review? There is a difference: it is usually easier that the app gets approved if it has ever been approved, but the times are exactly the same, as far as I know.

Comment: I've see some tweet. @Injuanj